# Undefined function or variable 's' in Matlab when computing convolution integral

Tags: matlab, convolution, numerical-integration

I'm trying to write a loop that calculates the value of a definite integral at each step. The function F is very complicated. To put it in simple terms, it integrates a bunch of terms with respect to s, from s=tn-(n/2) to s=tn+(n/2). After the integration, F still has a variable t. So you can say F(t) = integral(f(s,t)), where f(s,t) is the big mess of terms after "int(" in the line "F = @t...". In the last line, I want to evaluate F(t) at t=tn after F computes the integral of f(s,t).

However, after running this, I get the error "Undefined function or variable 's'."

```
function [ bigTheta_n ] = Untitled( bigTheta_o, bigOmega_o )
nt=5001; %since (50-0)/.01 = 5000
dt = .01; % =H
H=.01;
l=.05;

bigTheta_n = ones(nt,1);
bigTheta_n(1)=bigTheta_o; %theta_o

bigOmega_n = ones(nt,1);
bigOmega_n(1)=bigOmega_o; %omega_o
littleOmega_n = ones(nt,1);

epsilon=10^(-6);
eta = epsilon*10;

t_o=0;

    function Keta = K(t)
        Keta = (422.11/eta)*exp((5*(4*((t-tn)^2)/eta^2)-1)^(-1))        
    end

    function F = F(t)
        F = int(Keta(eta*t-s)*littleOmega_n,s,tn-(n/2),tn+(n/2))
    end

for n=1:4999
    tn=t_o+n*dt;
    littleOmega_n(n) = bigOmega_n(n) - sin(bigTheta_n(n))*cos(2*pi*tn/epsilon)/(2*pi*l);
    F = @(t) int(Keta(eta*t-s)*littleOmega_n,s,tn-(n/2),tn+(n/2));
    bigTheta_n(n+1) = bigTheta_n(n) + H*F(tn)
end

end
```

Even if I get rid of the line "F = @(t)..." and replace it with the following (and place it below where Keta = K(t) is defined)

```
function F = F(t, ti, tf)
    F = int(Keta(eta*t-s)*littleOmega_n,s,ti,tf)
end
```

and then replace the final line of

```
bigTheta_n(n+1) = bigTheta_n(n) + H*F(tn)
```

with

```
bigTheta_n(n+1) = bigTheta_n(n) + H*F(tn, tn-(n/2), tn+(n/2))
```

I still get the same error "Undefined function or variable 's'."

Comment: What is this line `sys s`?

Comment: I removed it, and it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
F = @(t) int(@(s) Keta(eta*t-s)*littleOmega_n,s,tn-(n/2),tn+(n/2));
```

which makes the integrand an anonymous function taking an input `s`.

Comment: Even when trying that I still get the messages "Undefined function or variable 's'.", "Error in
Untitled/@(t)int(@(s)Keta(eta*t-s)*littleOmega_n,s,tn-(n/2),tn+(n/2))", and "Error in Untitled (line 34)
    bigTheta_n(n+1) = bigTheta_n(n) + H*F(tn);"

Comment: What is the `s` supposed to do? Is it the variable you are integrating with respect to, or is it something else? If it is something else, then you need to define it before using it.